# Script to download a Specific files from website with JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

in a local website that I use for watching videos, I wanna download the subtitles from it all the links of the subtitles are on the main source page of the website I can download them manually by opening the link in new tap and it downloads automatically by chrome but I wanna a script let me download them from the source page automaticity the number of the episodes 5-80 depends on the content but I don't know how to write it in js :(
the subtitle provided in two formats SRT and webvtt anything of them works fine for me.
and this is a sample from the website source page shown the patreen of th

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-8">Shades of BlueS01E01</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">File size : 363.5 MB</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" style="display:" data-s3="1" class="btn btn-success play" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#vodModal" data-webvtt="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/subtitles/Shades_of_BlueS01E01_1571670964.webvtt" data-srt="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/subtitles/Shades_of_BlueS01E01_1571670963.srt" data-token="" data-id="42783"
        data-cookie="series42783" data-title="Shades of BlueS01E01" data-url="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/videos/Shades_of_BlueS01E01_1571670943.mp4" data-url360="" data-url1080="">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"> </i> Play Now</a>
        <a href="#" style="display:none" class="btn btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"> </i> 
            <span>SOON</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<li class="episodeitem">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-8">Shades of BlueS01E02</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">File size : 405.2 MB</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" style="display:" data-s3="1" class="btn btn-success play" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vodModal" data-webvtt="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/subtitles/Shades_of_BlueS01E02_1571670894.webvtt" data-srt="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/subtitles/Shades_of_BlueS01E02_1571670894.srt" data-token="" data-id="42774" data-cookie="series42774" data-title="Shades of BlueS01E02" data-url="https://jnashdt2673.myvodu.app:8880/videos/Shades_of_BlueS01E02_1571670869.mp4" data-url360="" data-url1080="">
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"> </i> Play Now
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please inform us about what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try that much cuz I don't have enough experience I can read JS but I don't know how to write it I tried to find some tutorials and some scripts from stackoverflow but didn't work 4me

Comment: Update: my friend made this for me it gives me all the links in array in the console 
    `[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-webvtt]')].map((element, i) => element.getAttribute('data-webvtt'))` but we couldn't make it one the links one by one in new tap so it downloads automatically